# How the partitioning should be done for ubuntu on windows installed hdd?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have  1 TB hard disk installed in my laptop on which I have installed windows. Now I have 450 GB remaining in my hard disk. I'm planning to install ubuntu 14.04. So I just want to know how the partitioning should be done. I mean how much space has to be allocated for root,home and swap directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the root-partition 30 GB will be enough.

For the swap-partition choose the size just a bit bigger than your physical memory (RAM).

The size for the home-partition is really up to you, you may use the rest of disk-space for it. But this is really a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank  u for the reply. I have found in the ubuntu forum that 1 gb should be allocated for /boot while dual booting. Is that necessary?

Comment: normally that is not necessary. but what you shoul check is in which mode windows is installed. If windows is installed in UEFI-mode then you have to install Ubuntu in UEFI-mode too. If  Windows is installed in legacy-mode then you have to install Ubuntu in legacy-mode too. If you don't do like this, you get real headache.

Comment: How do I check it?

Comment: Look [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/29504-bios-mode-see-if-windows-boot-uefi-legacy-mode.html) to check it from Windows.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, open Disk Management, and shrink your main partition by however much you want to leave for Ubuntu. **Leave it as unallocated.**

Next, boot the Ubuntu install media, and tell it to "install alongside Windows". It will automatically install to the uncallocated space, and take care of creating the swap partition for you.

*Just FYI since you're new here: if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting and/or upvoting it :)*

Comment: This is the simplest and easiest answer, unless he/she requires extra tweaking.

Comment: @Android Dev . Thank u for the reply. But I want to partition the disk manually. So can u please tell how much space I have to give for root and home directories ?

Comment: @BabyboBNukes - don't give root and home their own partition. As for space, that's entirely your decision.

Comment: @BabyboBNukes You'll need to choose something else when installing Ubuntu.  I suggest root ( / ) = to 10 GB. Asking about home is knda like asking how big is a hole? Home is required for all the files you intend to have for Ubuntu; but it isn't required to be in a separate partition. Swap should be slightly larger than your physical memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear that how many partitions you have in your system! If you have only 1 primary partition and in that partition you've installed windows and  450GB space remaining in that partition then first you've to create another extended partition using that space! And slice that partition into 2 partition one for your ubuntu system and another for your ubuntu swap partition.

Then boot up ubuntu DVD. Install system select partition as other then choose / for the ubuntu partition and choose swap for the swap partition then continue! I'm in mobile if I go on pc I'll edit my answer in detail if you don't know how to do it.

Comment: There is no need to manually create the partitions. See my answer.

Comment: Yeah! There's a lot of way to doing so! But If someone do it manually then he will get whats going on under the hood! And for the first tine in my life when I installed ubuntu I didn't manually partitioned the hdd and somehow I lost all of my partition and became 1 partition with just ubuntu. So I afraid maybe new comer to ubuntu will make the same mistake I did and lose data. So I suggest to do manual partition. Its not that hard.

Comment: Agreed, and I personally always manually partition when I install.  But I am a guru in this area, and I think manually partitioning is not something a new user wants to do. As for why you lost your data, you probably accidentally selected "erase disk and install Ubuntu".